# Cannot use datetime2 functions in a PDF string

Tags: hyperref, texorpdfstring

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc,en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={ Month={\DTMmonthname{10}}}
}

\begin{document}
\DTMmonthname{10}
\end{document}
```

The PDF contains "October" which is great, but the metadata contains "10" and I want "October".

Looking closer, I see a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\DTMmonthname' on input line 7.
```

This explains why `\DTMmonthname{10}` was replaced with a simple `10`, but how can I resolve this function and then save the resulting string in the metadata?

---

I briefly tried the following, and as expected "No effect" was saved in the meta-data.

```
\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={ 
    Month={\texorpdfstring{\DTMmonthname{10}{No effect}}}
  }
}
```

I've seen lots of examples where people want special symbols like subscripts in tex, but accept something simpler in the PDF string, but that's not what I'm going for here.  "October" doesn't contain any special symbols (It could in other languages, but I'm sticking to english).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[datetime2 documentation](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf) says:

> If you want the month name or weekday name to appear in a section or chapter heading,
> it’s best to use the expandable commands provided by the language modules rather than
> the robust commands provided by datetime2-calc. Remember that you can’t use robust
> commands in PDF bookmarks and such commands may prevent case-changing in
> headers for page styles that use \MakeUppercase

So the answer is to use `\DTM<root-language>monthname{x}`.  Where `<root-language>` is `english`.

To ensure `\DTMenglishmonthname{x}` is available, be sure to have passed an english language option (`en-US`,`en-GB`,`en-CA`) to `datetime2`.

Because you are no longer using `\DTMmonthname` which would point to `\DTMenglishmonthname`, you no longer need to pass the `calc` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfinfo={Month={\DTMenglishmonthname{10}}}}

\begin{document}
\DTMenglishmonthname{10}
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdftk date.pdf dump_data | grep Month -A1
InfoKey: Month
InfoValue: October
```

Comment: `pdfinfo={ Month={\csname DTM\languagename monthname\endcsname{10}}}`  should work too (and will fall back to 10 if the language is not known).